# Fen.after function in python is weird

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm coding a Pong game in Tkinter but I got a problem with the fen.after function.

There's my code:

```
    if xballe2 >= largeur - epaisseur_barre and 0 <= yballe2 <= ypopo1:
        xballe1, yballe1, xballe2, yballe2 = largeur/2 - rayon, hauteur/2 - rayon, largeur/2 + rayon, hauteur/2 + rayon #the ball goes in the middle of the canvas
        fen.after(1000) #wait 1 sec before redefine its values 
        alpha = uniform(0, 2*pi)
        Vx = V * cos(alpha)
        Vy = V * sin(alpha)
        toto += 1
        score1.configure(text = toto)
```

I'd like to wait 1 sec before the ball restart. At this point the ball is already in the middle. But the opposite actually happens: python wait 1 sec before redefining the ball in the middle.

Why my code doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

The `*.after()` method is used to launch a timer that will run code after a certain amount of time has elapsed.  It returns immediately.  If you want to introduce a delay into your program, here are a couple of approaches -- since I don't have enough of your code to test them, these are conceptual approaches, you may have to do more to make them work:

**Conceptual approach #1**

```
def cleanup_frame()
        alpha = uniform(0, 2*pi)
        Vx = V * cos(alpha)
        Vy = V * sin(alpha)
        toto += 1
        score1.configure(text = toto)

if xballe2 >= largeur - epaisseur_barre and 0 <= yballe2 <= ypopo1:
        xballe1, yballe1, xballe2, yballe2 = largeur/2 - rayon, hauteur/2 - rayon, largeur/2 + rayon, hauteur/2 + rayon #the ball goes in the middle of the canvas
        fen.after(1000, cleanup_frame)  # wait 1 sec before redefine its values
```

**Conceptual approach #2**

```
import time

if xballe2 >= largeur - epaisseur_barre and 0 <= yballe2 <= ypopo1:
        xballe1, yballe1, xballe2, yballe2 = largeur/2 - rayon, hauteur/2 - rayon, largeur/2 + rayon, hauteur/2 + rayon #the ball goes in the middle of the canvas
        time.sleep(1)  # wait 1 sec before redefine its values 
        alpha = uniform(0, 2*pi)
        Vx = V * cos(alpha)
        Vy = V * sin(alpha)
        toto += 1
        score1.configure(text = toto)
```